# Ember Calling method inside the controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-controllers

here is my code I have to call another method inside the Ember controller
I was tried but this is not working I have confused in this...

please help me to what is wrong in this code?

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  ....

  getValue(){
    var a = 7 * 2;
    return a;
  },

  getResult(){
    var result = this.getValue(); // result is this.getValue is not function 
  }
});
```

Comment: How do you call the getResult function is important here. without the relevant code, this question is not answerable. voting to close

Answer (score 0):

First this code does not makes sense:

```
getValue(){
  var a = a * 2;
  return a;
},
```

here you're using `a` before you declare it.

---

but to answer your question: your code is correct.

[Here](https://ember-twiddle.com/aa3ffa41642d3401afe6253353fde5e0?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C) is a working example. I've just replaced `var a = a * 2;` by `var a = 7 * 2;` to make this code valid.

Comment: that *is* the answer. your code is correct. if that wasnt your problem, you dont have a problem (or dont post the relevant code).

Comment: i haven't access the getValue() its return this.getValue is not function

Comment: have you checked the twittle I linked? it works! If this does *not* work for you please provide a minimal not working example like a git repo or a twiddle.

Comment: for that you have access the method inside actions but i need this in custom function

Comment: how do you call this custom function? please show this code. probably there is your error.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that whatever is calling `getResult()` is not setting the context of `this` to the controller, and my hunch is that you'll need to put `getResults()` in the `actions` object.

Comment: its simple i can get the hash url from the window location and then check the last path of the url so i can make little function inside the controller to check the last path of the url (i know it will done by helper function ) so when calling the controller custom function inside the custom function i need to call that url check custom function i have tried but its return the function is not defined sorry I have not share my whole codes here